# JQuery - travel inside of elements using Each() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

How to travel inside the elements in JQuery using each function?

Consider this is my elements structure:

```
<div id="first-div">

    <div id="check-div1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="mobile-check"
            value="Mobile">Mobile
    </div>

    <div id="check-div2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="charger-check"
            value="Charger">Charger
    </div>

    <div id="check-div3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="headphone-check"
            value="Head Phone">Head Phone
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to print value of each checkbox in an alert using `each` method.

I tried the following

```
    $("#first-div").each(function(){
        alert($(this).id.div); // struck here to travel inner of first-div
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#first-div div').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).find('input').val();
  alert(val)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-div">

  <div id="check-div1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="mobile-check" value="Mobile">Mobile
  </div>

  <div id="check-div2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="charger-check" value="Charger">Charger
  </div>

  <div id="check-div3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="headphone-check" value="Head Phone">Head Phone
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this way

Answer (score 0):

You may mis-understand the usage of the `jquery selector` and the `.each` function, in your original code you are trying to loop by all elements with id `first-div`. You may want to study my reversion for more info - https://jsfiddle.net/mc594hcy/

Answer (score 0):

Do a console.log($('#first-div div input:checkbox')), This will help you see how the elements are selected. Then you can try this:

```js
 $.each($('#first-div div input:checkbox'), function(index, value){
   var divValue = $(value).val(); 
 alert(divValue);  
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="first-div">

    <div id="check-div1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="mobile-check"
            value="Mobile">Mobile
    </div>

    <div id="check-div2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="charger-check"
            value="Charger">Charger
    </div>

    <div id="check-div3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="headphone-check"
            value="Head Phone">Head Phone
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```